# Splitting expenses in a group

Tags: average, ratio

There are three friends A,B,C  in a shared room. For a period of 30 days, A and B contributed amounts of 137.5 and 79.62 during the whole month whereas C's contribution is 158 during 12 days only. How can the expenses for final settlement be split among the three friends at the end of the month ,considering the special case of C